# React Native - Get all results from database with SQLite and pass it to flatlist

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native, react-native-flatlist

**I am using this library: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage in my project.**

**I retrieve multiple rows from database like this:**

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dsFW.png)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmFq0.png)

[Flatlist - Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s5ih.png)

But I don't want to hardcode data in data array like this:

```
this.state = {
  data: [{worker_fname: 'John'}, {worker_fname: 'Harry'}]
};
```

I want to get data from the database without hardcode in array :)

Comment: did you tried something like this ```let rows = results.rows.raw(); ``` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Can you show me image or code?

Comment: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#step-3-write-application-javascript-code-using-the-sqlite-plugin check here

Comment: I check this documentation, but I want to get data from the database without hardcode and pass it to Flatlist and this link doesn't help me. Please, show me code or image for example :)

Comment: What you mean hardcode. you just need to change your setState to this        
 ```let rows = results.rows.raw(); 
this.setState({data:rows})```

Comment: And data array must be empty, right?

Comment: its up to you. it doesnt matter for React. when state change it will re-render component.

Comment: I don't want to add data manually. Look this code: https://imgur.com/a/XYK7pNw I must hardcode worker_fname in data array, I don't want this. I want to get data from SQLITE and pass it to Flatlist like this: https://imgur.com/a/kvVb4oj. But with FlatList and SQLite, no with ListView

Comment: Can you share what is  ```results.rows.raw(); ``` I need to see what it returns.

Comment: Yes: https://imgur.com/a/c4f63rS

Comment: I mean. in console.log. what is your data.not code

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cK0Bjdb

Comment: Thank you! The error was with me there was no need to have a console.log(item)!